# How can I modify this loop to change the last print line?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def writetofile():
    myFile = open("C:\Jazmyn\myText.txt", "a")
    myFile.write(a)
    myFile.close()

# creating new text file, I have created a folder named "Jazmyn"
# in my C drive and the text file is created there. 


def greenbottles():
    bottle = ['Zero','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten' ]
    text_one = 'green bottles hanging on the wall'
    text_two = 'And if one green bottle should accidentally fall\nThere\'ll be'


for i in range(10, 0, -1):
    with open("C:\Jazmyn\myText.txt","a") as fo:
        print(bottle[i], text_one, file=fo)
        print(bottle[i], text_one, file=fo)
        print(text_two, bottle[i-1], text_one, file=fo)





greenbottles()
# this needs to be written to the file
```

I need the "One" line to change from bottles to bottle, as instead of it looking like this: One green bottles hanging on the wall
One green bottles hanging on the wall
to
One green bottle hanging on the wall
One green bottle hanging on the wall

Is it possible to just print the last part and write it to the file or can I modify the loop so it can change it?

Comment: how come you're using the variables of the function outside of it without declaring them global? Isn't some of the code missing?

Comment: The code is behaving as it should be? I am a beginner with python so i must admit i am not familiar with what you are saying.

Comment: There are a few general design mistakes you might want to fix - you are opening the text file twice, which is redundant, you don't need the first function (in fact, you don't need any of the functions). But what surprises me is that it's working for you at all, you should see a syntax error at the first print

Comment: I did notice when i play around with my code while i was trying to modify the loops and what not that sometimes i'll get an error like "bottle is not defined" What sort of syntax error should I be getting you think?

Comment: exactly that ('bottle is not defined'), because you defined it within a function and as such, you shouldn't be able to access it outside that function (unless declaring it a global). But you don't need even need to use a global, in your case, you just need to put all those lines outside of functions. only use functions for things your going to do more than once

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I didn't even realise it could cause a problem like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking something like:

```
def get_text_one(i):
    return "green bottle" + ("" if i == 1 else "s") + " hanging on the wall"
```

And then instead of:

```
print(bottle[i], text_one, file=fo)
```

do:

```
print(bottle[i], get_text_one(i), file=fo)
```

When you have a dynamic string, it probably shouldn't be a "static" global variable like you have `text_one` declared.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the global variables, I'll need to look into it further.